# How to configure jsreport-assets

Tags: jsreport

I am trying to use [jsreport-assets](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-assets) with [jsreport-core](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-core). But I get an error when I try to leverage an asset in my template, like this:

```
<img class="logo" src="{#asset myimage.png @encoding=dataURI}" />
```

Error: Asset myimage.png not found

I am confused about where to store my asset files and how to configure `jsreport-core` and/or `jsreport-assets` in order to leverage these assets.

Comment: howd you get it to work in your .net project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jsreport assets extension by default searches only in the local "database". You need to enable searching for local files, see [docs](https://jsreport.net/learn/assets#external-files-access).

```js
const jsreport = require('jsreport-core')()
jsreport.use(require('jsreport-assets')({ 
    searchOnDiskIfNotFoundInStore: true, 
    allowedFiles: '**/*.*' 
}))

jsreport.init().then(async () => {
    const res = await jsreport.render({
        template: {
            content: '{#asset foo.txt}',
            engine: 'none',
            recipe: 'html'
        }
    })

    console.log(res.content.toString())
})
```

Comment: do you have an example that shows how to do this in dotnet the docs are all JS